# Android Studio: Error:C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\asLocalRepo5_113e7t6m24zb1tcikv41hnqka\InitScript\initscript\cache.proper

Tags: java, android

Trying to get a program to compile.  Ive had Android Studio working on this machine before, but since I installed my printer, I haven't been able to get it to work again.  While compiling the program I get the message:

Error:C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\asLocalRepo5_113e7t6m24zb1tcikv41hnqka\InitScript\initscript\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Idea.log ends with:

INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\asLocalRepo5_113e7t6m24zb1tcikv41hnqka\InitScript\initscript\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2015-07-05 17:50:26,956 [2412420]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

From the drop down menu do below steps:

- `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...` and then restart to recreate the cache
- `Build > Clean Project`

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete C:\Users\User.gradle folder. then restart Android Studio Hope your Problem May solve